# Dynamic service routing on Docker swarm

Tags: docker, routes, docker-swarm, consul

I need to find a way to dynamically route requests to specific container of my service. I will make a simplified example of my application, to help you understand. I have a Rest API service running across a Docker swarm. The API has two endpoints.

The first endpoint creates a session with a unique `session_id`. Requests to this endpoint can be load balanced and hit any of my service instances without an issue. Then I have a second endpoint with a path argument like `/session_id` that needs to be routed to the service instance that originally created this session.

So lets say I scale my service to 3 instances and a new request to the first endpoint comes. The request, for example, hits the second instance of the 3. After a while a second request comes with the `session_id`, that was created before, as path argument. This request has to go to the second instance as well.

I know it's better to design stateless applications so you don't have problems like this one, but is not possible on this case. I searched a bit about [consul](https://www.consul.io/) and [ceryx](https://github.com/sourcelair/ceryx), but I am not sure it's possible with either of these tools.

Has anyone an idea how can I achieve a functionality like that? Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a load balancer with persistent/sticky session support.

Docker Enterprise supports this by configuring sticky sessions when creating a service.

```sh
$> docker service create \
 --name demo \
 --network demo \
 --detach=false \
 --replicas=5 \
 --label com.docker.lb.hosts=demo.local \
 --label com.docker.lb.sticky_session_cookie=session \
 --label com.docker.lb.port=8080 \
 --env METADATA="demo-sticky" \
 ehazlett/docker-demo
```

Refer to https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/interlock/usage/sessions/ for more information.

You can also achieve this using the [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/) load balancer. See [Deploy your Stateful Web Applications in Docker Swarm using Traefik Sticky Sessions](https://boxboat.com/2017/08/03/deploy-web-app-docker-swarm-sticky-sessions/) for a walk-through of how to configure this.